# VS Code Terminal Formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, visual-studio-code

I'm using Python3 and pandas in VS Code. Due to homeoffice, I got a smaller monitor than at work. I just printed a pandas dataframe, and as you can see in the picture, the format is odd - it puts the last few charakters of each row into a new line? Does anyone know why this happens?
If there are many columns, doesn't pandas automatically skip the middle ones to avoid this happening? Btw sorry for the greasing in the picture, had to cover some private data.

[image]

Comment: In VS Code, its internal terminal is used by default to integrate the terminal from the system. Therefore, please check whether your code is displayed normally in the system terminal. Also, please try to use [the 'cmd' terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_can-i-use-cmders-shell-with-the-terminal-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 10)` to limit the maximum width of columns when they are displayed.